# Check at runtime: how many implemented classes of an interface are existing (Java)

Tags: java, class, runtime, interface-implementation

I have tried a Java library for technical analysis of stocks (ta4j). It offers the following functionality:

- Create Rules:
  `Rule entryRule = new CrossedUpIndicatorRule(shortSma, longSma)
  .or(new CrossedDownIndicatorRule(closePrice, Decimal.valueOf("800")));`
- Create Strategies:
  `Strategy myStrategy = new Strategy(entryRule, exitRule);`
- Rules are derived from: `public interface Rule`
- Strategies are: `public class Strategy extends Object`

Detailed Javadocs can be found [here](https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/releases/archive/eu/verdelhan/ta4j/0.7/ta4j-0.7-javadoc.jar/!/index.html).

**Task:** In my application i want to offer a selection of the available strategies and offer a possibility to enter variables for the rules e.g. Decimal.valueOf("400").

**Question:** How can this be achieved if i want to detect the available strategies automatically at runtime?

**Vague idea for solution**: Change strategy class into an interface class and detect at runtime the implemented strategies with java reflection (?).

**My Java skills:** i have a good basic overview about Java but i am not an expert or professional.

Can you give me some hints how you would solve the task?

Comment: With reflection you can look at classes by name, but you don't know the names of the classes so you can't find them. What you'll need at low level to do this is a class loader that knows the class names. Or simply a class path scanning library that does all this for you: https://github.com/lukehutch/fast-classpath-scanner is one of the first results google gave me, no idea if it's any good.

Comment: You may want to implement a [service provider interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/SPI-intro.html); this way you don't have to use reflection at all.

Comment: Ta4j is not designed for RT optimization. To trace the execution of a strategy, have a look to [this example](http://github.com/mdeverdelhan/ta4j/blob/master/ta4j-examples/src/main/java/ta4jexamples/logging/StrategyExecutionLogging.java) about logging. There is no simple way to inspect every parameter of every indicator used in your strategy. More logs would have decreased the performances and led to readability problems (e.g. what is the difference between a SMA(12) and a SMA(14)? (since you may have several instances, with different arguments, of the same indicator type)).